# publish apk while keeping source code

Tags: android, google-play

I wrote an android app for someone, but they want the source code because supposedly they need it to send the app to the android market.

Are they making that up or is that legit? Is there anyway to give them the app so that they can claim credit for it without giving them the source code?

I suppose worst case I could just get their publishing creds and publish it from my computer as though I were them..

Thoughts?

Comment: This is a business question. Not a programming one. When you did work from someone, source code (who owns what) should be part of the contract.

Comment: They don't need the source code to publish it, if you've removed the debugging option from the manifest and so on

Comment: @MorrisonChang source code was NOT included in the specs, on purpose. I'm in the business of selling products, not recipes.

Comment: @Jackson In which case this is still a business question. You may want to sign it for them but then you would have to explain what a signing key is.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Touche. None-the-less, thanks for the good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need the source code to publish your app on the Android Market (now called Google Play Store). You just need a signed APK file.

Answer (score 2):

No, they do not need the source code, only the unsigned APK. In order for it to be published they will need to sign it using their own fingerprint, but that should allow them to freely publish without having access to the source code. Alternatively, you could sign the APK yourself and give them that, but this might not be preferable for them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they need a version. However you could just send them the signed apk and let them release it from google.

Comment: They will want to sign the .apk, I bet. They can sign an unsigned .apk though, yes. They don't strictly need the source code.